# Pandas DateTime plot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot the mean length and the number of messages extracted from a WhatsApp Chat. The `Data` dataframe contains the following columns:

- `Date&Time`, a pandas DateTime object;
- `msg`, the actual message;
- `name`, who sent the message;
- `msg_len`, the number of words in the message

Using the code below I create a stacked plot where on the X-axis there is the message grouped by the month. I found that if in a month no messages are exchanged the plot skip that month, I what to show that month with 0 messages then I plot the count or the mean. How can I modify my code?

```
Data = pd.DataFrame('./Wappmsg.txt')

Data['Date&Time']=pd.to_datetime(Data['Date&Time'], dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,1,
            figsize=(18,10),
            sharex = True)

group_by_month_per_user = Data.groupby([Data['Date&Time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), 'name']).count().unstack()

group_by_month_per_user['msg_len'].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=['name'], ax = axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('Number of text per month')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Count')

group_by_month_per_user = Data.groupby([Data['Date&Time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), 'name']).mean().unstack()

group_by_month_per_user['msg_len'].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=['name'], ax = axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('Mean lenght of a message per month')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Mean lenght')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Year-Month')

axes[1].legend()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add in an entry for each missing month and give it a value of zero. Then when you run the groupby command, it will still have those months. Posting your data or some example data with the right format to use your code would make it easier to demonstrate.